# Hadoop 2.6.2, start-dfs.sh dont start jobtacker and tasktracker

Tags: hadoop

I installed hadoop single node, and now Im starting the cluster with `start-dfs.sh` command.

But jobotracker and tasktracker are not appearing with `jps` command, so it seems that they are not starting.

Do you see why? Im installing the version 2.6.2...

After execute the command `start-dfs.sh`, this appears:

```
[hadoopadmin@hadoop ~]$ start-dfs.sh
16/03/23 12:17:19 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.2/logs/hadoop-hadoopadmin-namenode-hadoop.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.2/logs/hadoop-hadoopadmin-datanode-hadoop.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop-2.6.2/logs/hadoop-hadoopadmin-secondarynamenode-hadoop.out
16/03/23 12:17:37 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
[hadoopadmin@hadoop ~]$ jps
2881 DataNode
2758 NameNode
3142 Jps
3039 SecondaryNameNode
[hadoopadmin@hadoop ~]$
```

Comment: ever since 2012 or something, MR2 is the standard (using yarn). job and tasktrackers are somewhat pre-historic now. More info to get you up to speed can be read in this blog post from cloudera: http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/10/mr2-and-yarn-briefly-explained/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no JobTracker and TaskTracker anymore. We have NodeManager and resourceManager. Here you just started dfs services not started yarn services, to start yarn services run `start-yarn.sh` then only yarn related services will start.

If you want to start all services run `start-all.sh` (not a good practice)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in my example, I dont have any resource manager, it is normal dont appear resource manager with jps?

Comment: If you want to see yarn daemons you have to start yarn.sh then only you can see those with jps

Comment: Thanks! So we need to start yarn with start-yarn.sh and start also start-dfs.sh?

Comment: Yes.  You can start all by running start-all.sh

Comment: Thanks again! But we can or we should start all?

Comment: We can... Not we should